# Can't load ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can't display my `.txt` file in html page (local), with `.load`. File is in the same folder with `.js`.

```
$(function(){  
    $("#div1").load("text.txt");  
});
```

Comment: Is it in the same folder as the html page?  That's the one that matters.

Comment: Do you serve the pages with Apache or something similar? If yes try putting the relative path from the html file where your js is bound to the file `text.txt`.

Comment: is this local? the file needs to be hosted on a webserver for this to work...it cannot be on a local machine

Comment: @abc123 But he can have Apache or nginx or IIS or something else set up on his local machine. So it can be hosted on a webserver on the local machine. :)

Comment: Did you try full url? Like: www.example.com/test.txt (localhost/location/test.txt) ?

Comment: @abc123 Can you support your statement?

Comment: I think @abc123 means that `text.txt` can't be on his local machine as just a file sitting there in a folder expecting JS to read it (security restrictions), as opposed to some web accessible location in localhost

Comment: @Drakes Why `text.txt` wouldn't be loaded and fully displayed in the HTML page?

Comment: @D4V1D Easy. If the OP made a static html file and opened it from his desktop, then of course there would be a CORS restriction in effect if the jQuery tries to load `text.txt` from the same directory. OP never said he's running this script from a web server. ;)

Comment: @Drakes Of course..! It's kind of obvious that you need to run files (even static HTML) through a web server. Who still open their HTML pages by double-clicking on it? (and having file:/// URL? Yuks!). But you're right, it was worth mentioning it.

Comment: Where is the HTML part?

Comment: Have you tried in Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked, opening local files with local HTML will work in IE but not Chrome, Firefox, etc. due to security reasons.

If you're comfortable with HTML and javascript and want to run things locally and manipulate local files, have a look at [HTML Applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application) or `.hta`.  It's pretty neat.

Here is [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496.aspx) and here is [an example with Javascript](http://javascript.keithjoubert.com/hta-applications.htm).

> To avoid the Windows  system ActiveX warnings, your program should run
>   under an .hta envelope, ie, as an application (like an .exe file).
>
> The following code opens your application under the .hta "umbrella",
>   in a window of your sizing (in the example: 1030 x 95 pix) centered in
>   the lateral direction and low on the screen.  It does not allow
>   scrolling. Make a text file and save it under YourChoiceOfName.hta

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function Set(){   // this limits the size of the window opened and positions it
    var l=(screen.width/2 - 515); // centre - half the window width
    var t=(screen.height-130); // where you want it vertically
    self.moveTo(l,t);
    self.resizeTo('1030','95'); // as you can see, this example opens a longish but squat window, near the task-bar
  }
</script>
<TITLE>BlahBlah-The Progam</TITLE>
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="BlahBlah-App"
    BORDER="thin"
    INNERBORDER="no"
    SCROLL="no" 
    SCROLLFLAT="no"
    CAPTION="yes"    
    MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
    SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
    SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
    SYSMENU="yes"
    NAVIGABLE="yes"
    ICON="images/favicon.ico"
    WINDOWSTATE="normal">
<STYLE> body {margin:0} </STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload="Set()" >
<IFRAME src="blahblah.htm" application=yes width=1030 // width is that of your window
height=95 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0   /// height is that of your window
frameborder=0>Iframes not supported</IFRAME>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Note that you don't have to use an iframe as he does, you can put your HTML right in the HTA file.